# Connecting hands, so that fingers are woven together

Tags: phrase-request

How is the gesture called, when one connects palms together, letting fingers of one hand to go between fingers of the other, so that you're practically holding each hand with the other.

It's often associated with "So, let's get down to the business", also some people connect hands that way for prayer instead of just placing palms and fingers straight, together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of different options.

> He [clasped](https://www.google.com/search?q=clasped%20hands&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Aa73VKDCK4eeNoatgrgJ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1111&bih=799) his hands together.
>
> He [folded](https://www.google.com/search?q=clasped%20hands&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Aa73VKDCK4eeNoatgrgJ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1111&bih=799#tbm=isch&q=folded%20hands) his hands together.
>
> He [interlaced](https://www.google.com/search?q=clasped%20hands&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Aa73VKDCK4eeNoatgrgJ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1111&bih=799#tbm=isch&q=interlaced%20fingers) his fingers.

I'm sure there are a few others but these should be good for you.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that "clasped" is the activity and "folded" is the state? e.g. after you *clasp* your hands, your hands are *folded*?

Comment: Nope, they're pretty much interchangeable. You can say that your hands are *clasped* or *folded*.

Comment: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clasped+hands%2Cfolded+hands&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclasped%20hands%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfolded%20hands%3B%2Cc0) suggests in UK they fold hands about twice as often as they clasp them, while in USA it's vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The expression is to fold one's hands. See Collins, to fold no.2 meaning to bring together and intertwine  http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fold

If you fold your hands as for praying the fingers of one hand lie between the fingers of the other hand.